# Turnig off sql logging in JDO.

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdo, datanucleus

In my app I am using JDO and my sql is being displayed in the tomcat console window. I would like to know how to hide this SQL statements which are being displayed in the Console log.[image]

Answer (score 0):

So why not read the documentation for the software being used?
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/logging.html